# Access SqlLite Database which is shipped with application with SqlLite Database Browser

Tags: android, sqlite

I have copied database in Android Project folder and It is working fine. Now, I am inserting values in table. So I want to know that Is there anyway by which I can see those data using SqlLite Database Browser ???
Database in assets folder, I opened it but I can't see any new data.
**My Code to insert data:**, It is working fine, no errors.

```
public boolean SaveUserResponse(String QId, String OptionId,
            String ResponseDate) {
        try {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put("QId", QId);
            cv.put("OptionId", OptionId);
            cv.put("ResponseDate", ResponseDate);

            mDb.insert("tblUserResponse", null, cv);

            Log.d("SaveUserResponse", "User Response has been Saved.");
            return true;

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("SaveUserResponse", ex.toString());
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: How do you insert new data into DB?

Comment: by method and query in Android App.

Comment: please post your code and errors if any

Comment: you can not modify files from assets ... maybe on first start database  has been copied from assets to some other place and then used by your app ... but it just blind guessing

Comment: @Selvin, is there any trick by which i can see database data at a time of insertion ? like we can see data in sql server which inserting data from asp.net page.

Comment: use debugger, maybe your data is empty?

Comment: @nikis, it is showing inserted data in TextView but I want to access database using SqlLite Database Browser.

Comment: you can't grab it form `assets` folder, because this folder is in apk and has no absolute path. you have to copy it from `assets` to your folder if you want to pull it on your computer

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch your DB from device using `DDMS` (can be found under `android-sdk\tools`). There open `Device` -> `File Explorer`. Then navigate to `data\data\your_app` and pull your DB to a disk.

BTW, your DB shouldn't be placed under assets, here is a code how to copy it from assets (you can call it on the first run of your app):

```
void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    String DB_PATH = "/data/data/<app>/databases/";
    String DB_NAME = "db.sqlite";

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}
```

Comment: check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607468/error-copying-database I found many tutorials and they have said that put database in assets folder.